# C# get only top 10 highest selling items in database and put it to chart

Tags: c#, sql, database, charts

Hi everyone i already have a code to select products sales from a database and put it to chart, but its selecting all products. How can i get only 10?

And what should be the query if need the opposite which the top 10 least selling products?

Code:

```
  private void loadchart()
  {
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BENJOPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold from Sales_productholder group by ProductName", connection);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            this.chart1.Series["Pieces Sold"].Points.AddXY(read["ProductName"], read["QtySold"]);

        }
        read.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the least selling products, just change the order by in either of the answers to ascending `ORDER BY SUM(QtySold) ASC`

Comment: @AaronDietz ascending is the default, you need to change them to descending to get the top 10.

Comment: @juharr Right, whoops.  You're on fire man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold 
FROM Sales_productholder 
GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY SUM(QtySold) DESC

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold FROM Sales_productholder group by ProductName order by SUM(QtySold)", connection);
```

Comment: You need the order by to be `DESC` for top 10, right now that's the bottom ten.

Comment: Thank you sir. this is for the least selling right? shall i add DESC for the top selling?

Comment: @juharr You too sir!

Answer (score 2):

In sql-server you can use TOP 10

```
 "Select TOP 10  ProductName, Sum(QtySold) as QtySold 
   from Sales_productholder 
   group by ProductName
   order by Sum(QtySold) DESC"
```

Comment: Needs an order by to get the top 10 highest selling.

Comment: That's the bottom 10.  You need to order in descending order for the top 10.

Comment: Thanks  sir scais.